# grails 2.3.x async and sleep

Tags: grails, asynchronous, sleep, gpars

I got some strange behaviour using grails 2.3.x and async. I'm doing some test with this code:

```
def test1() {
    def list = new PromiseList()
    list << {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println "1"
        return "1"
    }
    list << {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println "2"
        return "2"
    }
    list << {
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        println "3"
        return  "3"
    }
    list.onComplete { List results ->
        println 'finished: '+results
    }
    list.onError { error ->
        error.printStackTrace()
    }
    render 'finish'
}
```

but in my log i got:

```
1
| Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1565)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1556)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:543) 
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.storeGrailsWebRequest(WebUtils.java:682)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.WebRequestPromsiseDecorator$_decorate_closure1.doCall(WebRequestPromiseDecoratorLookupStrategy.groovy:61)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1260)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
| Error     at groovyx.gpars.group.PGroup$3.call(PGroup.java:287)
| Error     at groovyx.gpars.group.PGroup$4.run(PGroup.java:311)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2
3
```

In fact the tasks (and onError closure) are executed, but onComplete is not (off course)!!

what am i doing wrong?

except for the Thread.sleep() is pratically code taken from doc: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html

Is Thread.sleep() not compatible with GPars for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `onComplete` does not block. The request/action does finish before your tasks and `list` goes out of scope.

You need to use `waitAll()` to wait for all tasks to finish before the action returns. Easiest is to replace the `onComplete` with

```
    def result = list.get ()
    println 'finished: ' + result
```

`list.get()` is implemented by calling `waitAll()`.